# How can I filter by search term condition in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

Each made a code to filter search terms by gender, nationality, purpose and age, but these apps are all working separately. I want to make this a result.
I'd like to know how to respond to various conditions at once. For example, if the sex and age are heard at once, I have to return the results on it, and I want to know how.
There are two things I want to solve here.
1.Apply condition overlay of all search results
2.When entering a page without searching, no list was printed

```
//base Object
    $penpals =  $this->penpalModel->getUsers();


    //name search
    if (!empty($request->name)) {
        $users = $this->userModel->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->name . '%')->get();
        if (!empty($users)) {

            $penpals->whereIn('user_id', $users);
        }        
    }


    //gender search
    if (!empty($request->gender) && $request->gender !== 'all') { 
        $penpals->leftJoin('users', 'penpals.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('penpals.*', 'users.gender')
        ->where('users.gender', $request->gender); 
    }


    // country search
    if (!empty($request->country) && $request->country !== 'all') { 
    $penpals->leftJoin('users', 'penpals.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select('penpals.*', 'users.country')
    ->where('users.country', $request->country); 
    }


     // goal search
     if (!empty($request->goal) && $request->goal !== 'all') {

        $penpals = $this->penpalModel->where('goal_id',$request->goal)->latest();
     }


    //age search
    if($request->ageMin != 1 || $request->ageMax != 100 ){

        $ageMin = floor($request->ageMin);
        $ageMax = floor($request->ageMax);

        $penpals = $this->penpalModel->leftJoin('users', 'penpals.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('penpals.*', 'users.age')
        ->whereBetween('users.age', [$ageMin, $ageMax])
        ->orderBy('penpals.created_at','desc');

    }


    //search result
    $penpalsData = $penpals->orderBy('penpals.created_at','desc')->paginate(12); 
$penpalsCount = count($penpalsData);

    return view('penpal.index')->with([
        'penpals'       => $penpalsData,
        'penpalsCount'  => $penpalsCount
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is build the object as you go along the search filters.

What you're doing currently is applying the filter and ending it abruptly and to each.

Apply each filter that is present first, then on the end execute the search.

Do it like so:

```
add filter (age).
add filter (nationality).
-> then finally execute search.
```

Not:

```
filter (age) -> search. execute.
filter (nationality) -> search. execute.
```

Here's the idea (of course this is not tested):

```
<?php


// $penpals =  $this->penpalModel->getUsers()->latest()->paginate(12);
// base penpals object
$penpals = $this->penpalModel;
// start out with the initial original object, untouched

// if nickname is present, add filter nickname
if (!empty($request->name)) {
    $users = $this->userModel->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->name . '%')->get();
    if (!empty($users)) {
        // apply | attached user ids found
        $penpals->whereIn('user_id', $users);
    }        
}
// dont cut off the query and execute yet, continually check other filters
if (!empty($request->gender) && $request->gender !== 'all') { 
    $penpals->leftJoin('users', 'penpals.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select('penpals.*', 'users.gender')
    ->where('users.gender', $request->gender); 
}
// again, continue to the next set of filters (country search)
// and so on, the same syntax, build off of the base object and continually connect filters

// then on the end, EXECUTE it!

$penpalsData = $penpals->orderBy('penpals.created_at','desc')->paginate(12); // execute then builder after several layers of filters are applied!
$penpalsCount = count($penpalsData);


return view('penpal.index')->with([
    'penpals'       => $penpalsData,
    'penpalsCount'  => $penpalsCount
]);
```

Just follow this idea or concept, this isn't your copy the answer and works type. Modify it and fit it properly to your business logic.

Comment: @박보근hi remove the email above, its sensitive data, the error not unique means you're getting the same name, use alias `users a u` and `penpals as p` to avoid it

Comment: I solved it using the whereHas() function. Thank you for the tip

Comment: @박보근 okay I understand, by the way please remove the comment above with the email sample data. if its coming from your customers data, then it is sensitive

Comment: Don't worry, it's just dummy data. I'm a student and this is my hobby. Thank you.